# Restoring the balance between anchor text of external links

Tags: seo, links, anchor

In past 2 years, we've created so many links using same keywords related to our business in general as anchor text, but few links pertaining to our brand/domain name. Now we believe google considers most of these links as spam and this leads to poor results in SERP (second to the fifth page in 2 years).

Now we consider three ways to restore the balance between these links:

1- Creating new links with brand/domain anchor text. 
2- Purchasing links with brand/domain anchor text from sites like Fiverr.
3- Disavowing current links in Google.
Deleting these links is not an option as they are widespread through the web.

Which one is better? If there is a better way please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

I would no worry too much about Google flagging those old links as spam. What we have seen lately is that (Specially since the last algorithm update) Google is just demoting or ignoring those links completely not penalising you for it. How to confirm this? Check your **Search Console** for Partial or Site-wide penalty. If you have a partial penalty do nothing. However, if you do have a site-wide penalty submit a reconsideration request **(option 3)**.

**What should you do moving forward**

Definitely start a more "organic" approach to lnikbuilding using your brand/domain **(option 1)**. Ask good neighbors for links, use Social Media, etc.  But, whatever you do, DO NOT embark in a crazy crusade for automated or fiverr links or any other "provider" **(option 2)**. For god sake, learn the lesson :)

**Changing Domain** (my no desirable option 4)

Consider, among other reasons, changing the domain and implementing the strategies to leverage you old domain with 301s if not penalised.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, purchasing backlinks, a BIG NO, you shouldn't be thinking about it.

I would say, link on brand should be OK provided you got a good balance in compare to other keywords. Think in this way, if someone would love your product/brand, they will naturally link to your product/brand, it's absolutely OK to have.

To answer your last 3 points:

Firstly, more than anything you should create a good quality content which user will love.

And then, when it comes to link building, it's hard and tough. Do not use shortcut methods. Focus on quality than quantity and build authority.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

From the sound of what you've done is over-optimise the anchor text for your domain and Google will not let you on page one.

The best tip we can give you is to examine what your competitors are doing in relation to their links.

Take your target KW, find the top 5 competitors for KW and then find the links that they've built by using all of the three main aggregators:

Ahrefs/Majestic/MOZ

Copy the linking profiles and look to have targeted anchors no more than 5% of the time